# How to back up OSMAnd favourites using ADB?

Tags: adb, backup, osmand

First attempt to back up favourites to my PC after enabling USB debugging and connecting the phone to the PC:

1. Open [OSMAnd+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.osmand.plus) 4.6.11
2. Click the hamburger menu
3. Click *Settings*
4. Click *Export to file*
5. Expand *My Places*
6. Check *Favourites*
7. Click *Continue*
8. Give up because there's no option to save to a local file

Second attempt, based on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/OsmAnd/comments/nuo95z/anyway_to_backup_osmand_data/):

1. `adb pull /storage/[ID omitted]/Android/data/net.osmand.plus`
2. Give up because `net.osmand.plus/files/favourites.gpx` has no favourites

Third attempt, based on [this](https://github.com/osmandapp/Osmand/issues/6441#issuecomment-456181305):

1. `adb backup -f osmand.ab net.osmand.plus`
2. Unlock phone and answer backup prompt
3. Give up because `osmand.ab` is some 47 bytes

How do I actually do a backup of favourites from my phone to my PC using ADB? The phone is *not rooted.*

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in a [comment relating to the export issue mentioned above](https://github.com/osmandapp/OsmAnd/issues/18926#issuecomment-1901028949), there is a working solution to this:

1. Open OSMAnd+
2. Click the hamburger menu
3. Click *Settings*
4. Click *OsmAnd settings*
5. Click *Data storage folder*
6. Choose an **external** storage and follow the instructions

After this I was able to back up favourites by running `adb pull /sdcard/Android/data/net.osmand.plus/files/favorites` (your path may vary).